# how to view iPhoto 11 photos on Apple TV (3rd gen)?

Tags: photos.app, appletv

I have shared a photo album iPhoto 11 (using Preferences > Sharing > Share My Photos > Share Selected Album.

I have an Apple TV (3rd generation) and I'm trying to view the shared photo album on it.

How do I view my shared iPhoto album on my Apple TV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Mac, enable photo sharing in iTunes.  Don't know why you have to use iTunes - I guess ATV doesn't know how to read the iPhoto library directly.  I'm not in front of my Mac, but you can Google the photo sharing menu command if it's not obvious.

On the ATV3, go to the Computer menu/icon, click on your computer name if needed, then go to Photos.  Your shared albums should be in there.

From the main Settings menu/icon, you should be able to select one of your albums to use as the slide show.

That said, it's easier to use Photo Stream!  Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Thx. `iTunes > File > Home Sharing > Choose Photos to share with Apple TV...` -- that's some wicked usability n Apple's part there. ;)

Comment: Glad it helped.  This isn't specific to ATV3, by the way.  The same thing works for ATV2 (Apple TV 2), which is probably obvious, but I'm adding it here to help with search-ability.