# Can I view my home network's iPhoto / Photos library on an Apple TV?

Tags: icloud, photos, appletv

I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere yet, but I'm curious if it is still possible on the Apple TV to view your iPhoto/Photos library from a computer on your LAN [like you could before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/76567/86913) without using iCloud?

Previously, you could go to the 'Computers' icon on the Apple TV and view a shared iTunes library on another computer on your home LAN (as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76558/how-to-view-iphoto-11-photos-on-apple-tv-3rd-gen)). Though it didn't connect directly to iPhoto/Photos, it was able to see your home collection via iTunes. I use this feature quite a bit when showing home pictures and videos to folks on my HDTV.

After seeing some of the reviews of the new 4th gen Apple TV in late 2015, I saw that you could still connect to your local iTunes library, but the option for viewing your photo library was no longer visible; I don't know if this was because of the reviewer not having a library switched on or if the feature has been removed.

I am still on a 3rd gen AppleTV which always allowed me to view photos from my LAN's Mac Pro. Home Sharing is still enabled as it has always been. I have, however, upgraded from iPhoto to Photos in the last few months and also kept up-to-date with the latest iTunes releases. Unfortunately, I've only just noticed that under 'Computers' on the TV I no longer see Photos as a viewable item despite Music/Movies/etc still being there. Going into iTunes preferences I do have home sharing enabled, but no options visible specifically for Photos there.

Any idea if this is still possible? Was this removed by the move to Photos from iPhoto or was it a recent iTunes release that killed it? Frankly, the apparent removal of the feature from the 4th gen TV was a bit of a show stopper for me since I don't particularly care about the new app capability of the device, but mostly I refuse to upload my gigabytes of personal media to Apple's servers (nor do I want to pay for it when I have my own storage solution).

Thanks!